# Pthread Concepts

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I'm studying threads and I am not sure if I understand some concepts. What is the difference between preemption and yield? So far I know that preemption is a forced yield but I am not sure what it actually means. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yielding is done within the application. Preemption is done outside the application (by the OS).

Answer (score 1):

Preemption is when one thread stops another thread from running so that it may run.

To yield is when a thread voluntarily gives up processor time.

Comment: when we preempt though, it doesn't mean that the running thread will necessarily run to finish?

Comment: No, my understanding is that the thread is stopped from running, having not finished it's task, another thread will run, once it has finished (or it's time slice has ended) then the first thread can be reconsider to run again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a gander at these...

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29)

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is how the OS is entered.

'yield' is a software interrupt AKA system call, one of the many that may result in a change in the set of running threads, (there are lots of other system calls that can do this - blocking reads, synchronization calls). yield() is called from a running thread and may result in another ready, (but not running), thread of the same priority being run instead of the calling thread - if there is one.

The exact behaviour of yield() is somewhat hardware/OS/language-dependent. Unless you are developing low-level lock-free thread comms mechanisms, and you are very good at it, it's best to just forget about yield().

Preemption is the act of interrupting one thread and dispatching another in its place.  It can only occur after a hardware interrupt.  When hardware interrupts, its driver is entered.  The driver may decide that it can usefully make a thread ready, (eg. a thread is blocked on a read() call to the driver and the driver has accumulated a nice, big buffer of data).  The driver can do this by signaling a semaphore and exiting via. the OS, (which provides an entry point for just such a purpose).  This driver exit path causes a reschedule and, probably, makes the read thread running instead of some other thread that was running before the interrupt - the other thread has been preempted.  Essentially and simply, preemption occurs when the OS decides to interrupt-return to a different set of threads  than the one that was interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

***Yield***: The thread calls a function in the scheduler, which potentially "parks" that thread, and starts another one. The other thread is one which called yield earlier, and now appears to return from it. Many functions can have yielding semantics, such as reading from a device.

**Preempt**: an external event comes into the system: some kind of interrupt (clock, network data arriving, disk I/O completing ...).  Whichever thread is running at that time is suspended, and the machine is running operating system code the interrupt context. When the interrupt is serviced, and it's time to return from the interrupt, a scheduling decision can be made to keep the interrupted thread parked, and instead resume another one. That is a preemption. If/when that original thread gets to run again, the context which was saved by the interrupt will be activated and it will pick up exactly where it left off.

Scheduling systems which rely on yield exclusively are called "cooperative" or "cooperative multitasking" as opposed to "preemptive".

Traditional (read: old, 1970's and 80's) Unix is cooperatively multitasked in the kernel, with a preemptive user space. The kernel routines are trusted to yield in a reasonable time, and so preemption is disabled when running kernel code. This greatly simplifies kernel coding and improves reliability, at the expense of performance, especially when multiple processors are introduced.  Linux was like this for many years.